# Convert_tz on Now() returns error

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, utc

I'm trying to insert a row into a table and include a pseudo-timestamp (the field is type datetime instead of timestamp):

```
INSERT INTO CustomFieldValues 
    (CustomField, Name
    , Description, SortOrder
    , Creator, Created
    , LastUpdatedBy, LastUpdated
    , Category)
VALUES
    (99, 'Value Ninety Nine'
     , '', 1001
     , 8809, now()
     , 8809, now()
     , 'Cat1');
```

If I insert the value of now(), the datetime is in local time where all other rows are in UTC.

If I try to convert Now into UTC time using Convert_tz, I get NULL:

```
SELECT convert_tz(now(), '-08:00', '+00.00') as UTC_Time

UTC_Time
--------------------
NULL
```

Why won't this work? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: select convert_tz(cast(now() as datetime), '-08:00', '+00.00') also returns NULL

Comment: addtime(now(), '08:00:00') gives me the right time, but doesn't feel elegant... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT convert_tz(now(), '-08:00', '+00:00')
because  use for convert TZ to TZ  chouse be +00:00

Answer (score 0):

You need to load timezone table in mysql

```
shell> mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

More on 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html